# Debian 3.1 "Sarge" installing PHP5

Tags: php, debian

I am trying to install PHP 5 on my old debian machine. But cannot get it working.

Looks like I cannot find a working repository to install PHP 5 and I get a lot of error for dependencies and missing packages.

Can anyone give me a working tutorial to do it?

I am on PHP 4 and I need PHP 5 to run wordpress..

I need a working PHP5 repository for my Debian version: Debian 3.1 "Sarge"

Please help me out, this is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: Sarge is about seven years old, and has not been maintained (even for security updates) in the last four years. You need to upgrade immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I really hope its not a security-critical online server; please upgrade? :p
http://www.debian.org/releases/etch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html

anyway, if you absolutely dont want to upgrade,
try

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

-- http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/php5.htm

Answer (score 0):

This should be good:

http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/apachephp5.htm